# Append result of stored procedure to earlier executed stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a stored procedure which takes a single parameter containing single value.
I want to pass a collection of values to the procedure one by one and get the combined result into one table . Is this possible ?

Currently I am  using cursor to execute procedure in loop but only  result from passing first value in the collection is obtained.

```
declare @clientid varchar(10)

create table #tmpp(secid varchar(10))
insert into #tmpp values(2319)
insert into #tmpp values(2855)
insert into #tmpp values(1303)


    declare cur CURSOR LOCAL for
        select secid from #tmpp 

    open cur

    fetch next from cur into @seclientid

    while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN



    exec getReportforclient @clientid
        fetch next from cur into @clientid
    END

    close cur
    deallocate cur
    drop table #tmpp
```

If this is too obfuscated / unclear/ silly, can somebody please provide me an alternative ? 
Any help is most appreciated . Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There probably is a way to this without using cursors, but without taking a look at your stored procedure we can't help too much on that. You can create a table (temporary or not) that has the same structure that the results of your sp and insert the results into it. Something like this:

```
DECLARE @clientid VARCHAR(10)

CREATE TABLE #tmpp(secid VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO #tmpp VALUES(2319)
INSERT INTO #tmpp VALUES(2855)
INSERT INTO #tmpp VALUES(1303)


CREATE TABLE #Results(col1 INT, col2.... -- create the table that will hold your 
                                         -- results

DECLARE cur CURSOR LOCAL for
SELECT secid 
FROM #tmpp 

OPEN cur
FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @seclientid
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #Results
    exec getReportforclient @clientid

    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @clientid
END

CLOSE cur
DEALLOCATE cur
DROP TABLE #tmpp

SELECT *
FROM #Results
```

Comment: @m.hasan not in this case, since you are trying to insert the results of your sp, and you can't do `EXEC somesp INTO #Table`. For this to work, you need to previously create the table

Comment: Ok , is there a way to find the structure of result of stored procedure so that I may know the number of columns to create and each column datatype ?

Comment: @m.hasan Well, I assumed that it was your sp and that you already did know that. I think that the easier way would be to look at the code of your stored procedure.

Comment: @m.hasan There is a restriction that you can use only one `INSERT INTO - EXEC` on your query. So, if your `getReportforclient` sp is also inserting values from another sp, then you can't insert the results of that sp on another table

Answer (score 1):

Loop without CURSOR

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#tmpp') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tmpp   
CREATE TABLE #tmpp(Clientid varchar(10))
INSERT #tmpp values(2319), (2855), (1303)

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#Results') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Results  
CREATE TABLE #Results(--output columns of procedure)                                        

DECLARE @Clientid int = (SELECT MIN(Clientid) FROM #tmpp)

WHILE (@Clientid IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN  
  INSERT INTO #Results
  EXEC getReportforclient @Clientid   
SELECT @Clientid = MIN(Clientid) FROM #tmpp WHERE Clientid > @Clientid
END
```

Simple example on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7ef6e/3/0)

Comment: @m.hasan I tested my script and it works. Simple example on SQLFiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7ef6e/3/0